# How to plot on log-type axis with LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice

I have some data and want to represent it on log type x-axis

How to do that with LO Calc?

Comment: After you make your chart, right-click on the chart and choose edit. Then hover the mouse on the x-axis and the tooltip should show "x-axis". Right-click again and choose "format axis" and there you'll get an option to specify "logarithmic".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The option to use a logarithmic scale depends on the **chart type**: you won't see that option for the x scale if, e.g., you've selected "column" or "line". You **need** to select "**XY (Scatter)**" and then select "logarithmic scale" in the X axis properties:

[image]

[image]

Comment: this actually works for line charts as well, at least in LibreOffice 3.5.7.2

Comment: @nietaki where do you see the option? I just created a line graph in 4.3.7.2 and I can't find any option for axes.

Comment: Self-answer: select the graph with (double?) left click and do Format > Axis > Axis Y. See also https://help.libreoffice.org/Chart/Scale